# Can I raid with only 2 people?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is it possible to complete any raid bosses in Borderlands 2 with only 2 people? Or are they really that hard? Answers that cover both true vault hunter mode and ultra vault hunter mode would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. The question is regarding strategies (at a high level), obstacle clearing (raid bosses), game mechanics (are raids possible for two people, or not? e.g., the mechanics of WoW prohibit such behaviors: raids are for 10+ people, and anything less is not likely to succeed by use of intended mechanics).

Comment: Further, it's clearly NOT about pirated games, game identification, opinion-based answers (see above), identification, or too many answers. (And I realize these are just guidelines, but I still think it is appropriate). Admittedly, it could be phrased clearer, e.e. "do the mechanics allow for the possibility of the average pair of players to beat a raid boss?". But I don't think that really conveys anything my question doesn't. 3 down votes seems harsh.

Comment: Hi Jan, i think you're misunderstanding the voting system. If it were any of those things, it would be closed, not down voted. Down voting is for when you think a question doesn't show effort on the part of the asker, isn't generally useful or a 'good question'. For example, just asking 'is X possible?' doesn't attract useful answer (yes, or no are the two options). If you're having difficulty with a strategy for a particular fight, you could ask a more specific question that solicits useful information.

Comment: "I'm trying to clear the raid bosses from Borderlands 2, but only with 2 players. It's possible or they are too hard to do (with only 2)?" - You are not asking HOW... just IF it possible, I think this is the reason behind the down-votes.

Comment: @michel don't get bogged down in trying to use language to weasel something out of the on topic box. Please. It's clear what's being asked; the fact that it's phrased as "can I do this" rather than "how do I do this" is a semantic rabbit hole that isn't worth following.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz thanks for pointing that out =) will take care next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely possible, my friend and I completed the whole game on every difficulty, every boss, just him and I. It might be difficult at some points, but it is totally possible, just need the right equipment.

Comment: Your welcome, enjoy the game! Make sure to farm for some good equipment too. Get a good sandhawk if you have the scarlet's booty dlc too, its good with the bee shield

Answer (score 4):

The "raid bosses" in Borderlands 2 are designed for 4-players, but they *can* be beaten with fewer.  It takes good players, good teamwork, and careful builds, but it can be done.

If you're just doing it for the achievements, you can always decrease the difficulty by going back to a previous playthrough.  My wife-slash-co-op-partner is not a particularly hardcore player, so the two of us opted to play on TVHM when we were leveled for UVHM.  This didn't make them trivial, but it did make them doable for the two of us.  Our goal was achievements and "having seen all the content" so the lower difficulty didn't bother us.

The Borderlands Wikia gives strategies for various combinations of parties and raid bosses, for instance, here's the strategy page for [Terramorphous.](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/You._Will._Die._(Seriously.))  Be prepared to respec and relearn what role you will play.

Sometimes, farming legendary gear will make these fights easier, but they're extremely rare and you're going to spend a *lot* of time farming them if you need them.  (There was a "Loot Hunt" event recently that made a lot of them more common for a short time, though)

Having specific characters can also be critical - for instance, a Siren with Res.  If you haven't been playing a Siren, you might have a tougher time or you might have to consider power-leveling one for some of these "low party count" tactics to work.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, it definitely seems possible, yet very difficult.  Raid bosses are meant for 4 players, so it would seem logical to do so, but I should assume you only have 1 or 2 friends who play Borderlands 2, like myself. I have also read that there are a few places to hide and shoot where you will be generally safe. My suggestion? Farm for legendary equipment, like The Bee (Available from Hunter Hellquist) And the Infinity Pistol (Available from Doc. Mercy) There are more legendary equipment that can help, so you should be able to have a pretty good selection.

Comment: The bee and infinity pistol combo is basically worthless since they fixed a glitch giving the infinity pistol more than one bullet a shot. We like experience too, I played this game with just one friend the whole time, all dlc and modes we beat everything. Sure we may have exploited a few things, but who doesn't? :) Oh and your gonna want to get the light blue weapons.....dpn't remember what they are called, but they are above legendary status.

Comment: pearlesants are what they are called....and you want them...trust me